# É possivel testar e validar vários modelos de redes neurais ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: python, redes-neurais, deep-learning

Tenho uma rede neural recorrente feita com pytorch, e gostaria de saber se tem como testar essa rede com configurações diferentes, por exemplo, com vários valores diferentes para o learning rate, momentum e numero de neurônios nas camadas ocultas de forma automática e no final me retornar qual modelo teve o melhor desempenho, ou eu tenho que ir alterando esses valores manualmente e testando uma por uma ate encontrar a melhor configuração ?

Comment: Sim, é possível, e existem diferentes estratégias para isso. Busque pelo termo *grid search*, por exemplo aqui: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html.

Comment: valeu, ajudou de mais @jfaccioni hehehehehe.